# Disable heads-up notifications

Tags: notifications, settings

How to disable heads-up notifications (pop-up notifications)?

(These are the notifications that show at the upper part of the screen and obstruct the view.)

Comment: You can use adb for this. `adb shell settings put global heads_up_notifications_enabled 0` should do the trick

Comment: @Aayush Where should I type this?

Answer (score 3):

First of all you'll have to install adb on your pc and then connect your phone and run the commands

### Installing ADB

1. Download adb installer from [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2FWTNmSn&v=496EBFITOAs&event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbFdMVUQ0VXpzYWhsOVYzQTVFbk1xMWMweE52d3xBQ3Jtc0ttbkFpUzZkNnhYZTRseUdkalZtN0dxbUpzaHNmbl8tVndmZndweVJTeXNYV3BXbEdIQW94c1h6S2x1dVpCQW9NMXkzWmk4M1prZFVFNFl5d2dkZHlNaE1xWTNoTTBjRWI3clRkdXVWYV9PU01tUVZPcw%3D%3D) on your pc
2. Run the setup and do as directed to install adb.
   See [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=496EBFITOAs) video for reference

### Connecting device and running command

1. To use ADB with your Android device, you must enable a feature called USB debugging. Open your phone’s app drawer, tap the Settings icon, and select “About Phone”. Scroll all the way down and tap the “Build Number” item seven times. You should get a message saying you are now a developer.
2. Head back to the main Settings page, and you should see a new option near the bottom called “Developer Options”. Open that, and enable “USB Debugging”.
3. Later on, when you connect your phone to your computer, you’ll see a popup entitled “Allow USB Debugging?” on your phone. Check the “Always allow from this computer” box and tap OK. Select connection type to MTP from charge only if this doesn't pop up.

   Take a look at [THIS](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/amp/) if you're stuck somewhere.. Everything mentioned above is demonstrated here with pictures
4. Now open command prompt and type `adb devices`. You'll see a device listed there.
5. Enter `adb shell settings put global heads_up_notifications_enabled 0` to distable it. And if you want to enable it back again enter `adb shell settings put global heads_up_notifications_enabled 1`

Comment: Does this command need to be run after every reboot of the phone?

Comment: Nope...........

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Applications & Notifications> Notifications.

Comment: This affects the normal notifications, but not the so-called heads-up notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet tested; probably doesn't show anything (not even in the status bar) and also disables sounds:

- Go to *Settings -> Apps -> App info*
- For each app that shows heads-up notifications:

  - Tap on that app
  - Tap on *App notifications*
  - For each type of notifications ("Lite" (the cryptically named Facebook app) has about 20 types):

    - Tap on the name of the type of notification
    - Tap *Importance -> Low (No sound or visual interruption)*