# How to disable "banner" notifications on Android 11?

Tags: notifications

I would like to disable "banner" notifications globally or on a per app basis, including for applications that don't internally provide a disable method.

By banner notifications, I mean like in the following example:

[image: android 11 banner notification from Signal]

Note that when googling, there is a great deal of terminology confusion around "banner," "pop-up," "pop-down," "pop-head," and "bubble" notifications. On this website, every answer I found dealt with "bubble" notifications, which look like this:

[image: example of a bubble notification]

My phone is a pixel 4a. My android version is 11.

**How can I disable banner notifications?**

Comment: Possibly a dupe of [Disable heads-up notifications](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230455/44325) or its linked questions.

Comment: Correct, though I believe my question gives more information, and, that question hasn't accepted an answer yet. In any case, https://android.stackexchange.com/a/230547/126090 was a solution that worked for me.